# Allow new user to access existing tables of a tablespace Oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-sqldeveloper, tablespace

I have created a new user in Oracle and want to give full privileges to this user for a particular tablespace i.e. see all tables/views, select, update, delete etc. that exist in the tablespace (whether those tables/views are created by any user, I still want this new user to be able to have full access to them)

After creating the user like below

```
create user WAS identified by WAS default tablespace TS_DDMS;
```

When I login into Oracle SQL developer with this new user, I dont see any existing tables/views that were created by other users/schemas even though I gave following permissions to this user.

```
grant connect to WAS;
grant create any view to WAS;
grant create session to WAS; 
grant create view to WAS;
grant unlimited tablespace to WAS;
grant resource to WAS;
```

P.S: I can see the tables that I create with this user itself though.

Comment: Tables, views, stored procedures and many other database objects are schema objects (own by a user\schema). SQL Developer shows you database objects that you own. To be able to access objects owned by another user(schema), that other user has to give you appropriate object privileges.

Comment: How? please specify?

Comment: [There you go](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21642/privileges.htm#TTSQL338) or/and [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm#i1009117)

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I still can not see tables created by other user/schemas.

Comment: I did `grant all privileges to WAS;` and it worked fine.

Comment: Then you should be able to see other users objects when you expand "Other Users\<<USER_NAME>>". Those objects will not be displayed when you are browsing your own schema.